# How to use function defined at helper into scaffold generate template?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I defined a function at `application_helper`

```
  def title(page_title)
    content_for :title, page_title.to_s
  end
```

and I custom scaffold edit template(`lib/templates/erb/scaffold/edit.html.erb`)

```
<% title "Edit " + plural_table_name.capitalize+@<%=singular_table_name %>.id.to_s %>

<%%= render 'form' %>
```

But when I run `rails g scaffold subject title:string contents:text`, there occurs an error:

> 'template': undefined method 'title'

Please tell me how to use `title` in the scaffold template to auto generate.

Comment: Given that a helper is just a Ruby Module, you can simply include it **somewhere** to use it. Did you try just to `<% include ApplicationHelper %>` in your edit.html.erb? You may need to require it before though, I'm not sure if autoload of constants is enabled within the scaffolding engine.

Comment: scaffold does not evaluate these methods. it will work even if you don't define them since all it is doing it generating file with that content in it. so they don't necessarily need to be defined or included. Also i tried to do the same setup and it works for me. you probably have an error elsewhere.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you should use `<%%` instead of `<%` same as:

```
<%% title "Edit " + plural_table_name.capitalize+@<%=singular_table_name %>.id.to_s %>
```

Because the `title` is a function that not define in scaffold lib and don't nedd compile when run `generate scaffold`.

Answer (score 0):

I think there's a bit of a misunderstanding here. Here's what a scaffold is, according to [Rails Guides](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/command_line.html):

> A scaffold in Rails is a full set of model, database migration for
>   that model, controller to manipulate it, views to view and manipulate
>   the data, and a test suite for each of the above.

So when you say `rails g scaffold subject title:string contents:text`, you are creating a model, `Subject`, with the attributes `title` (of type string) and `contents` (of type text), and all the files that can be automatically created with it.

From there, you can use `title` in your .erb files. For example:

```
<% title "Edit " + plural_table_name.capitalize %>

<%= render 'form' %>
```

Also, I'm not sure what you are trying to do here: `plural_table_name.capitalize+@<%=singular_table_name %>.id.to_s`, but I'm fairly certain that is not valid.